# How to display multiple values seperated by commas in database and display as a dropdown

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress i need to select multiple values seperated by commas in single column as a dropdown by exploding commas.

I have values in DB like as 7.00 am t0 8.00pm,7 am t0 9 pm...

How i use select query to select this and display as a dropdown by removing commas in wordpress.

Comment: Explode then loop through array and show in dropdown

Comment: Have you tried to use `exclude()` to make those array elements , than you can make that as dropdown.

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show us some code? Your question is a tad hard to understand and it would be easier to with the code.

Comment: Try the default query for selecting record, there is not different method for dropdown. Use the `explode(your_array);`, and then use for loop for getting the data in dropdown. Add your code whatever you tried.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to select using GROUP_CONCAT to have all the dates separated by comma and then you use explode to create an array with the dates.

Here are examples and documentation for the GROUP_CONCAT function:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php